# Angular 5 Material Sidenav without main content

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am working on create an Angular 5 site and trying to get the sidenav working specifically for smaller screen sizes.

(Ref: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview)

Is there a way to implement the sidenav without having to place main content within the element? I just want a side form with links and it does not show unless I add the `mat-sidenav-content` and populate it with data. I have to have the format:

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav>
    <mat-nav-list>
      ..links..
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    ..content that fills screen..
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I do not want that `mat-sidenav-content` to be required. It's not required for the generic MaterializeCSS framework: http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html.

Essentially I want the ability to separate my header from the main content but this sidenav thing is forcing me to place the main content within my header...

Any ideas?

Comment: is it causing any issues? I have my app set up with everything inside of the mat-sidenav, then in I have our router-outlets inside the mat-sidenav-content and then our header is loaded as a component from there

Comment: It's not causing issues, just seems weird to me. Do you have the ability to open/close your side nav? We want a hamburger menu in the top left that is only shown on smaller screens that opens/closes the side nav.

Comment: Yeah totally, the nested components can call a service to even change the side-nav content / behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: I didn't want to place the main content inside the side navigation, but I wanted to call the side menu from my header to the full screen, then I did it and it helped me:

```html
    <mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
      <mat-sidenav>
        <mat-nav-list>
          code...
        </mat-nav-list>
      </mat-sidenav>
    </mat-sidenav-container>

    <div>other main content</div>
```

```css
    .sidenav-container {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
```

I placed the navigation container on the entire screen, but hid it so that it did not interfere with the main content and the side navigation worked as I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The mat-sidenav element is positioned absolutely. Therefore, it does not affect the mat-sidenav-container's height. This is likely to ensure that mat-sidenav-content defines the height of the content area that the sidenav is positioned for and to support the over mode. If mat-sidenav-content does not have content, mat-sidenav-container will not have a height. There are three potential solutions for displaying the container without content.

1. Set mat-sidenav-container's and all block-level parents' height to 100% up to the containing block that defines the maximum available space. This will not work if the container has siblings.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vonuxq)

```css
html, body, .mat-sidenav-container {
  height: 100%;
}
```

2. Set a static height on the mat-sidenav-container.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmndxj)

```css
.mat-sidenav-container {
  height: 100px;
}
```

3. Use a directive to set the sidenav's position to relative when there is no content.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bmndxj)

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'mat-sidenav-container[appSupportEmpty]'
})
export class SupportEmptySidenavDirective implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChild(MatSidenavContent, { read: ElementRef }) contentRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  @ContentChildren(MatSidenav, { read: ElementRef }) sidenavRefs: ElementRef<HTMLElement>[];

  constructor(
    private container: MatSidenavContainer, private elementRef: ElementRef<HTMLElement>
  ) { }

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    if (!this.contentRef.nativeElement.hasChildNodes()) {
      this.sidenavRefs.forEach(ref => ref.nativeElement.style.position = 'relative');
    }
  }
}
```